# how to avoid promise rejection when firing 'error' event with EventEmitter in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, es6-promise

I have code that looks like

var EventEmitter = require('events');

```
class MyClass extends EventEmitter{
    doSomething(){
        this.emit('error', new Error('this is why') );
    }
}


function doSomethingAsync(){
    return new Promise( (resolve,reject) =>{
        new MyClass().doSomething();
        resolve();
    });

}


process.on('unhandledRejection', function(reason){
    console.error('unhandled rejection', reason, reason.stack);
});


setTimeout( doSomethingAsync,1);
```

If I don't assign an `error` event handler with `myClass.on('error', ()=>{ ... })` the `unhandledRejection` handler is triggered when the `error` event is thrown and `doSomething` flow is interrupted (I don't see the `after` print)
if I add a handler, everything works fine (I do see the `after` print).

How can I avoid this? Why should an 'error' event cause a promise rejection?

sometimes I don't care if an event emitter throws an error event. but I will always care if a promise failed. 
is this wrong? should I treat them the same?

using nodejs 4.2.1

## Edit

Ok, so I learned that node treats unhandled 'error' in a special way, and if unhandled it will throw an exception.

https://strongloop.com/strongblog/robust-node-applications-error-handling/

is there a way around it? I don't see why this choice of implementation in nodejs is correct.

shouldn't there be a global handler like `unhandledErrorEvent` instead? like they added to `unhandledRejection`?

Comment: Can you provide us a full example to reproduce this issue?

Comment: I'll try. give me a sec.

Comment: @Ginden done.. see updated question code snippet

Answer (score 4):

I agree, that is very annoying and I am gonna investigate that further in Node core.

In the meanwhile you can check for listeners with [`emitter.listeners(name)`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_listeners_eventname), which is actually nice enough.

```
if (this.listeners('error').length > 0) this.emit('error', err)
```

I find your question to be a very good catch.

Comment: Faced the same issue. I solved it by adding `.on("error", ()=>{})` after eventEmitter instantiation.